# How to use sql LEFT JOIN query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables which are **booking** and **CurrentDay_Booking**.

```
**booking**:

ID  bookingdate  TableID   starttime   endtime    userID   NumberOfPeople  phoneNumber  EmailID    
 1  2015-11-20   1         11:15:00    11:55:00   john     2               21029917     gmail.com    
 2  2015-11-20   1         11:15:00    11:40:00   riyas    2               21029917     gmail.com    
 3  2015-11-20   1         12:15:00    12:45:00   riyas    2               21029917     gmail.com
 4  2015-11-21   2         11:20:00    11:30:00   riyas    2               21029917     gmail.com

**CurrentDay_Booking**:

ID  bookingdate TableID    starttime   endtime    userID   NumberOfPeople  phoneNumber  EmailID    
 1  2015-11-20   1         11:15:00    11:55:00   john     2               21029917     gmail.com
```

My question is: need to put data from **booking** table to **CurrentDay_Booking** that, not equel to **CurrentDay_Booking** ID and equel to current date and starttime and endtime between or equel to current time

I got current time and current date working with different query

I don't know how to make the query with where clause and LEFT JOIN

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    t.ID,
    t.bookingdate,
    t.TableID,
    t.starttime,
    t.endtime,
    t.userID,
    t.NumberOfPeople,
    t.phoneNumber,
    t.EmailID
FROM booking t
LEFT JOIN CurrentDay_Booking s 
ON t.ID = s.ID
WHERE s.ID is null
    and t.bookingdate='" . $cur_gmt_date . "'
    and t.starttime <= '" . $cur_gmt_time24 . "'
    and t.endtime => '" . $cur_gmt_time24 . "';
```

I think that I 'm putting condition in wrong place.

Please any one help, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Correct... move your "AND" components of the criteria to the LEFT JOIN via... ON T.ID = S.ID AND T.bookingdate....

Comment: i am not able to work out even i tried, please can you edit the query, thanks

Comment: Before I try to offer just a corrected left-join syntax, can you please describe what it is you are trying to accomplish? Both table structures are identical, and the first line in the second is the same as the first table.  Is this for something like a restaurant lunch / dinner reservations? how many in the party?  Rely on phone number to prevent duplicates?  Same people/phone, but different time periods?  What are you looking to get.

Comment: Thanks. Actually this is an Table reservation system.

Comment: Every 2 seconds this query run and check the booking database for current day  booking, like if current time between booking starttime and endtime, if available then bring all the rows will saved in table CurrentDay_Booking. Then after 2 seconds again check booking table and will do same job but the query will find out table CurrentDay_Booking have same ID, query not pickup from table booking.

Comment: its not LEFT JOINT, but LEFT JOIN :D lol, check it out - joint - https://www.google.com/search?q=joint&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=HRNPVsj2JMG4UKOMjtgM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you are describing, it does not make any sense to create a table as a result of a table being added to as in your scenario described.  The result table is the same, so why not just do a direct query from the table holding all the bookings for the specific day in question.  No join needed to another table based on was it already there or not

```
SELECT
      t.ID,
      t.bookingdate,
      t.TableID,
      t.starttime,
      t.endtime,
      t.userID,
      t.NumberOfPeople,
      t.phoneNumber,
      t.EmailID
   FROM 
      booking t
   WHERE 
      t.bookingdate='" . $cur_gmt_date . "'
```

With an index on you "booking" table based on (bookingdate), it does not have to compare on what was already there or not.  Then you don't have to worry about purging it every day just to begin a new day.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. this is works. but not meet my requirement.

Comment: @rwahid, I understand it doesn't meet the need of your secondary table, but duplicating just to duplicate is not what querying and normalization is about.